# Why is there an Overflow in this DateTime?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, date-arithmetic

I am trying to create a dynamic calendar where I can ignore weekends and skip ahead to 45 days from now

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '12/01/2015'

;With NumberList AS
(
        Select *
        From 
        (
            Select Rank() Over(Order By S1.Id, S2.Id) Number
            From master.dbo.SysObjects S1, master.dbo.SysObjects S2
        ) XX
        Where Number < 1000
)
,FullCalendar as
(
    select Cast (dateadd(day, number,  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) as Date) CalendarDate
    from Numberlist
)
,CalendarWithNumbers As 
(
    Select CalendarDate, Row_Number() Over (Order By CalendarDate) DayNumber
    From FullCalendar
    Where ((DATEPART(dw, CalendarDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
)
,StartingDate as
(
    Select *
    From CalendarWithNumbers
    Where 1=1
        And CalendarDate = @StartDate
)
Select @StartDate StartDate, CalendarDate NDaysFromNow, DayNumber
From CalendarWithNumbers 
Where DayNumber = (Select DayNumber + 45 from StartingDate)
```

However, I get an an Overflow Error

```
StartDate  NDaysFromNow DayNumber
---------- ------------ --------------------
Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.
```

However, I am only choosing the first 1000 numbers in my first CTE, and my starting date is the first day of the year.  `1/1/2015` + 1000 days only goes up to `9/26/2017`.

Why I am getting an Overflow Error?

---

### EDIT - Comments added to explain code

I added a comments to the code to make it easier to understand.

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '12/01/2015'

;With NumberList AS
(
        /* Get a list of 1000 Numbers*/
        Select *
        From 
        (
            /* 
                Get a sequence of Numbers (I get 2071*2071 = 4289041) 
                I may need to go up to 50 years in the future so I have to do a cartesian product (same as Cross Join)
                However, this is where it fails
            */

            Select Rank() Over(Order By S1.Id, S2.Id) Number
            From master.dbo.SysObjects S1, master.dbo.SysObjects S2

            /*
                comment out the Select ABOVE 
                Uncomment the Select BELOW
                It works!!
                Probably because now the sequencing only goes up to 2071
            */
            --Select Rank() Over(Order By S1.Id) Number
            --From master.dbo.SysObjects S1

        ) XX
        Where Number < 1000
)
--Select * From NumberList
--UnComment just the line above, and comment everything below to see the result just up to there

,FullCalendar as
(
    /* Take the first day of the year, and add 1 to 1000 days to it
    It starts from 2015-01-02 (bug needs to be fixed so it starts from 2015-01-01)
    It ends at 2017-09-26
    */
    select Cast (dateadd(day, number,  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) as Date) CalendarDate
    from Numberlist
)
--Select * From FullCalendar
--UnComment just the line above, and comment everything below to see the result just up to there

,CalendarWithNumbers As 
(
    /* 
    WHERE CLAUSE exclude the weekend days
    ROW_NUMBER now number each day sequentially and save it in the DayNumber column
    */
    Select CalendarDate, Row_Number() Over (Order By CalendarDate) DayNumber
    From FullCalendar
    Where ((DATEPART(dw, CalendarDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
)
--Select * From CalendarWithNumbers
--UnComment just the line above, and comment everything below to see the result just up to there

,StartingDate as
(
    /* Get the DayNumber (from the query above) for the starting day*/
    Select *
    From CalendarWithNumbers
    Where 1=1
        And CalendarDate = @StartDate
)
--Select * From StartingDate
--UnComment just the line above, and comment everything below to see the result just up to there

/* 
    Now calculate 45 days from the daynumber in starting date
    that gives you the value for NDays from StartDate
*/
Select 
    SD.CalendarDate,
    Sd.DayNumber,
    CWN.CalendarDate NDaysFromNow, 
    CWN.DayNumber
From CalendarWithNumbers CWN
Inner Join StartingDate SD
    On CWN.DayNumber = SD.DayNumber + 345
```

Comment: this make my brain ouchies.  So... if you run it even with `where number < 2` you still get the same error.  This is super hard (at least for me) to mentally parse... any way you can throw some comments in perhaps each section and why its there?  add 21 example, what's the for?  Also one of your last statements "1/1/2015 + 1000 days only goes up to 9/27/2015"  I don't really understand that statement, as there's only 365 days in a year, how could you add 1000 days and still be within the same year?  Granted, my not understanding the statement is probably due to me not understanding the SQL.

Comment: You are not adding 1k days but the sum of 1 to1k years select DATEADD(yy, 500500, getdate())

Comment: You're using query this complex to get one day as result? There must be a way to do this without calculating the dates for 1000 days, twice.

Comment: @Kritner, I added comments. Also, it should have been `9/27/2017` (my bad).

Comment: @jean, I don't see how it goes up to 500500 because if you run each part by itself, the output stops at 1000 rows every time until the part where I eliminate weekends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that SQL Server decides to do things in different order than you think, and actually this:

```
;With NumberList AS
(
        Select *
        From 
        (
            Select Rank() Over(Order By S1.Id, S2.Id) Number
            From master.dbo.SysObjects S1, master.dbo.SysObjects S2
        ) XX
        Where Number < 1000
)
```

Doesn't get filtered to 999 rows before this happens;

```
select Cast (dateadd(day, number,  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) as Date) CalendarDate
```

Even though that's what you expect to happen. If you change it to this, the error will go away:

```
;With NumberList AS
(
  Select top 999 row_number() Over(Order By (select null)) Number
  From master.dbo.SysObjects S1 cross join master.dbo.SysObjects S2
)
```

Using `top` is usually a lot better option, because that gives the optimizer a better understanding about how many rows will be actually coming from there, instead of having to decide when to filter out rows with Number >= 1000 (or what the distribution of the numbers might be)

Comment: You're right, @JamesZ, it is because the optimizer is performing the date related operations before the cutoff happens.  I changed this to using 36500 (100 years) instead of 999 to cover my extreme boundary conditions.  That worked like a charm.

Comment: `TOP` is hardcoded.. you can't change that without changing the code.  That's why I chose `WHERE`.

Comment: @RajMore Top doesn't have to be hard coded, you can use variables too, it just has to be in select top (@rows) row_number()... format then

Answer (score 1):

This works ,,,, just replaced the query that generates the `NumberList`

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '12/01/2015'  --<-- I would use '20151201'

;With NumberList AS
(
        Select *
        From 
        (
            Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By (SELECT NULL)) Number
            From master..spt_values S1
        ) XX
        Where Number < 1000
)
,FullCalendar as
(
    select Cast (dateadd(day, number,  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) as Date) CalendarDate
    from Numberlist
)
,CalendarWithNumbers As 
(
    Select CalendarDate, Row_Number() Over (Order By CalendarDate) DayNumber
    From FullCalendar
    Where ((DATEPART(dw, CalendarDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
)
,StartingDate as
(
    Select *
    From CalendarWithNumbers
    Where 1=1
        And CalendarDate = @StartDate
)
Select @StartDate StartDate, CalendarDate NDaysFromNow, DayNumber
From CalendarWithNumbers 
Where DayNumber = (Select DayNumber + 45 from StartingDate)
```